# countdown plugin not works in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code

```
<div class="bigBgPaper">
<div id="regLogo"></div>
<div id="regAucHead"></div>
<div id="rightRed">
</div>

<nav class="mainNav">
    @Html.ActionLink("ჩემი პროფილი", "Index", "Profile")
    <div class="smallKub"></div>
    @Html.ActionLink("პრიზები", "Index", "Prizes")
    <div class="smallKub"></div>
    @Html.ActionLink("აუქციონი", "Index", "Auction", null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
    <div class="smallKub"></div>
    @Html.ActionLink("გამარჯვებულები", "Index", "Winners")
</nav>

<div class="auqcPrize">
    <div class="prizeOverflow">
        <div class="prizePic"></div>
        <div class="prizeLeft"><p>@ViewBag.countLeft</p></div>
    </div>
    <span>Lenovo</span>
    <br />
    <span>IdeaPad G50-30</span>
    <br />
    <span>CPU: 2160</span>
    <br />
    <span>RAM: 2GB</span>
</div>
<div id="monaw">
    <span>მონაწილეები</span>
    <div id="monawline"></div>
</div>
<div id="cowndtdownDIv">
    <span>დასრულებამდე</span>
    <div id="timer"></div>
</div>

<div id="betdiv">
    @Html.Partial("Bet")
</div>

</div>
<span id="clock"></span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/countdown/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var liftoffTime = new Date();
        liftoffTime.setDate(liftoffTime.getDate() + 5);
        $('#clock').countdown({ until: liftoffTime, padZeroes: true });
    });
</script>
```

this code works in html file but not works in cshtml. in console it says

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

and there's red underline at `$('#clock').countdown({ until: liftoffTime, padZeroes: true });`

Why?

---

I've copy pasted it in new solution and there works.. It's facebook application if it's something imprtant

---

I've moved jquery and fb sdk in head section in Layout and delete second jquery there. Now works

Comment: Are both `jquery.plugin.js` and `jquery.countdown.min.js` are loaded? you can check them in network tab of chrome development tools. If they are not, then it's the root of the issue. Maybe path is incorrect, or you didn't add them somehow

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Here is the same code - http://jsfiddle.net/t8u475u0/. The problem is with script loading. You are using `src="~/Scripts/countdown/jquery.plugin.js"` but it's not server side block. It's just a text, and it is rendered as the same text into html. And it won't be loaded on the page as browser doesn't know what `~` symbol means.

You should use `Url.Content` method that will replace `~` symbol to the root of site

The correct version should be:

```
<span id="clock"></span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/countdown/jquery.plugin.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js")"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var liftoffTime = new Date();
        liftoffTime.setDate(liftoffTime.getDate() + 5);
        $('#clock').countdown({ until: liftoffTime, padZeroes: true });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've changed it but same result :\

Comment: Can you update your question with rendered html with this block?